# Spring Security OAuth2 custom success user

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I want to add OAuth authorization wuth Azure AD. I use [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory) to setup this. The problem is that I want to use Azure AD only as a Trust Provider(like user belong to specific group aka directory), but I don't want to work with `OidcUser` Spring Security User.

Process that I would like to have: redirect user to Microsoft login page, receive user info with all tokens, handle request on my server side and authoriza my custom implementation of Spring Security `UserDetails` based on email from Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your scenario is to eliminate the user authentication completely and your server to directly authenticate then it is possible with [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow#:%7E:text=%20Client%20Credential%20Flow%20%282-legged%20OAuth%29%20%201,3%20Step%203%3A%20Make%20API%20Requests%20More%20).

Based on the process you have mentioned in the second paragraph which involves user it is possible with [authentication code flow.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context)

Also, for code sample and implementation please refer [Microsoft Github Document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/spring-security-web-app).